# Compare two tables in different databases and change one table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two databases in the same sql instance. One is backup2 which is a restored backup of my original database.

```
Database Table
Original.Payments
Backup2.Payments
```

I have two fields in each that I need to compare:

```
PaymentsId - guid
IsProcessed - bit
```

I need to compare the PaymentsId in each and if the payment exists in Backup2 and is marked Processed, I need to mark the Original.Payments.Backup as true.

I have the first part of the query done but I'm not sure how to link it to the Original database:

```
SELECT [PaymentId]
      ,[CorporationId]
      ,[IsProcessed]
  FROM [Backup2].[Web].[Payment]
 WHERE CorporationId = '2aa2dfw-20d2-4694-8e01-72288a1e8d4' 
   and IsProcessed = 'true'
```

This gives me my list of payments but I need to compare those to the original database and I'm not sure how.

Where do I go from here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `update` with `join` syntax

```
update OP
set IsProcessed = 'true'
FROM [Original].[Payments].[Backup] OP
JOIN [Backup2].[Web].[Payment] BP
on OP.PaymentId = BP.PaymentId
and BP.corporationId = '2aa2dfw-20d2-4694-8e01-72288a1e8d4'
and BP.IsProcessed ='true'
and OP.corporationId = '2aa2dfw-20d2-4694-8e01-72288a1e8d4'
```

Comment: Is this a typo `[Original].[Payments].[Backup]` ?

Comment: This got me what I needed with a few minor adjustments. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should be a start

```
SELECT [p1].[PaymentId]
      ,[p1].[CorporationId]
      ,[p1].[IsProcessed]
  FROM [Backup2].[Web].[Payment]  as [p1]
  JOIN [Original].[Web].[Payment] as [p2]
    on [p2].[CorporationId] = [p1].[CorporationId] 
   AND [p2].[PaymentId] = [p1].[PaymentId] 
   AND [p1].[CorporationId] = '2aa2dfw-20d2-4694-8e01-72288a1e8d4' 
   and [p1].[IsProcessed =]'true'
```